# Reform Angular Directive to use a "helper" for jqueryUi Resizeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have a directive in angular whos purpose is to provide Resizeable functionality from jqueryUi. The directive looks like this :

```
directive('resizable', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        callback: '&onResize'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.resizable({aspectRatio: true});
        elem.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
            if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
        });
        window.e = elem;
    }
};
```

The issue that I am currently having is that It works like a charm in Chrome and Safari. Everything is smooth as silk. In firefox I can very smoothly expand the window ..... but making it smaller again is very very quirky  (if it works at all). I found a post that said that in some cases what I may need is a helper function that will essentially create an empty div ... resize that ... then snap the original content to it.

From what I understand the helper functionality I need looks like this :

```
helper: function() {
    return (jQuery("<div>").css({ 
        height: jQuery(this).height(), 
        width: jQuery(this).width() 
    }).addClass('resizeHelper')); 
}, 
stop: function( event, ui ) { 
    var left = ui.position.left + 'px'; 
    var top = ui.position.top + 'px'; 
    jQuery(this).css({left: left, top: top}); 
}
```

My question is ... How do I incorporate that helper stuff into my directive properly, and for those out there who im sure have run into this same issue ... is this the way to go about fixing it?

Plunker Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ws64rm?p=preview

Comment: Can you setup a plunker please

Comment: plunker is up (check post above for link). I do not see the bug im describing with the test i show here ... but when something larger is loaded into the resize div (such as a swf) the issue is apparent in Firefox .